extract parts of filenames with regex in bash
I want to extract some information from filenames using regex in bash, which I will use to rename them according to BIDS. Here are the filenames:
ACC_svs_ECC.nii.gz
ACC_svs_noECC.nii.gz
ACC_svs_ref.nii.gz
Lt Hippocampus_svs_ECC.nii.gz
Lt Hippocampus_svs_noECC.nii.gz
Lt Hippocampus_svs_ref.nii.gz

Those are literally the only possibilities for filenames, not a pattern or example. all the filenames. each participant will have those 6 for two of their sessions, but the filenames will be the same until I change them to be BIDS compliant. The json files are sidecar files, so the filename is exactly the same as the .nii.gz except .json files.
Each filename has a brain region (ACC or Lt Hippocampus) and a type of mrs file (ECC, noECC, and ref). Those are the information that I will need in the new filenames, so as I loop through each existing filename I'd like to use them in the new filename.
Here is what the code will look like:
#!/bin/bash

ID=$1 # participant ID= user input
ses=$2 # session no (MRI)= user input
bidsdir=path/path/sub-001/ses-MRI1/mrs/ # path to mrs folder as specified by BIDS

for file in "${bidsdir}"; do
   voi= # either ACC of Lt Hippocampus
   type= # either ECC, noECC, or ref
   ext= # file extension- either .nii.gz or .json
   newfilename="sub-${ID}_ses-${ses}_voi-${voi}_acq-svs_${type}_mrs.${ext}"
   # rest of code to rename each file
   mv $bidsdir$file $bidsdir$newfilename
done

I'm used to using regex with python, and I'm pretty good at it, but I don't have time to spend another hour on figuring it out in bash. Here's how far I've gotten with the regex itself:
(?P<voi>ACC|Lt\ Hippocampus)_svs_(?P<type>ECC|noECC|ref)

please update the code to show where you're setting and referencing the regex; also update the code to show what you're assigning to variables voi, type and ext

do all filenames have exactly 2 underscores and two periods? if we remove everything after the periods we're left with a string that has 2 underscore delimiters ... will this portion of the filename always have the format brain-region + _ + literal string svs + _ + type?

the code mentions ext could be .json ... please update the sample data to include a couple files with the extension .json

[[ $file =~ (ACC|Lt Hippocampus)_svs_(ECC|noECC|ref).*(nii[.]gz|json)$ ]] && declare -p BASH_REMATCH

Bash uses POSIX Extended Regular Expression syntax. The RE you showed but don't use does not follow that syntax.

@markp-fuso I didn't add .json files to save space. The .json files are sidecar files to .nii.gz so the filenames are exactly the same, except the extension. Regarding your second question- yes. The examples I povided are all possible variations of the filenames.

@Shawn I don't know what that means. I usually use regex101 to write my regex and then click 'python' on the left side. I don't have any other regex experience hence my question

please update the question wtih the additional details; not everyone is going to read through the comments trying to piece together the whole picture

What @Shawn said means the regexp you have in your question (which looks like it might be a non-POSIX Perl-Compatible Regular Expression, i.e. a PCRE, maybe with some python-isms, idk) isn't a good starting point for writing a regexp that bash would understand (i.e. a POSIX-compliant Extended Regular Expression, ERE).

Please [edit] your question to show the expected output - your requirements aren't clear yet and sample input is only half of what we need to be able to test a potential solution with.

@EdMorton it's more time efficient to use itertools.product in python, you can easily generate the expected output that way based on the information in the post. happy to share the code if you don't know how. But it's also provided in the answer below (even tho code is not working).

consider reviewing minimal reproducible example and then updating the question accordingly; keep in mind most of the people who review this question may not know what BIDS and sidecar files are, and in this case it doesn't matter, what matters is the (very) basic requirement to parse a file name; if you have time to post comments and offer python/itertools code to generate the desired output then it shouldn't be that hard to run python/itertools on your system and just cut-n-paste the output into the question

@markp-fuso I do think the output is obvious based on my question (i.e. newfilename variable), especially considering the comments I provided next to the voi and type variables. I also did write which part of the code is not working in the comment to that answer (note my comment was made 5 hours ago, and the answer was edited 4 hours ago).

@Julia I think you replied to the wrong person as your comment seems unrelated to mine.

I don't see where in your script you are applying a regex. Also, many details (for instance the for loop) are irrelevant to the problem. Create a simple, reproducible example for your problem, show your attempt to solve it and explain where your attempt fails.

@user1934428 That's because I am not applying regex because I don't know how (which is why I am asking this question). How can I create a more reproducible example if I have already provided everything that I know how to do. If you don't know the answer after I specified everything I know or if you understand the question you can just click on a different question. Yet you chose to comment on a question that is already solved just to tell me that my question is stupid.

Many people try to use the bash regex operator, but don't do it correctly, so it is pretty normal to have a question about it, which shows an attempt to do it. The regex operator inside the [[ ... ]] command is written as =~, and if you grep the bash man page for this string, you will quickly find an explanation of how to use it, and also a link to the regex language supported by bash (which is not as powerful as the one you are used from Python).  Also, googling for bash regex examples gives you plenty of hits, so we can expect that you can at least make an attempt from this.

See for instance the stackoverflow how to ask page and the answers to this discussion for hints how to improve your question.

Assumptions:

file name format will always have 2 underscores and one or two periods
file name format will always have the format: <brain-region> + _ + <some-string-to-ignore> + _ + <type> + { .nii.gz or .json }

Adding a .json entry to OP's list of file names:
$ ls -1 /tmp/testd
ACC_svs_ECC.nii.gz
ACC_svs_noECC.nii.gz
ACC_svs_ref.nii.gz
'Lt Hippocampus_svs_ECC.nii.gz'
'Lt Hippocampus_svs_noECC.nii.gz'
'Lt Hippocampus_svs_ref.json'
'Lt Hippocampus_svs_ref.nii.gz'

In this particular case I'd skip the hassles/complexities of a regex and use a combination of parameter substitution (to strip off the path) and the bash / read builtin (in conjunction with dual delimiters _ and .) to parse the file names into the desired variables:
ID='myid'
ses='myses'
bidsdir='/tmp/testd'

for path_file in "${bidsdir}"/*{.nii.gz,.json}
do
    oldfilename="${path_file##*/}"                         # strip off the path (via parameter substitution)
    IFS='_.' read -r voi x type ext <<< "${oldfilename}"   # parse old file name into variables based on dual delimimters "_" and "."

    newfilename="sub-${ID}_ses-${ses}_voi-${voi}_acq-svs_${type}_mrs.${ext}"

    echo "path/file = ${path_file}"
    echo "old file  = ${oldfilename}"
    echo "new file  = ${newfilename}"
    echo ""
done

This generates:
path/file = /tmp/testd/ACC_svs_ECC.nii.gz
old file  = ACC_svs_ECC.nii.gz
new file  = sub-myid_ses-myses_voi-ACC_acq-svs_ECC_mrs.nii.gz

path/file = /tmp/testd/ACC_svs_noECC.nii.gz
old file  = ACC_svs_noECC.nii.gz
new file  = sub-myid_ses-myses_voi-ACC_acq-svs_noECC_mrs.nii.gz

path/file = /tmp/testd/ACC_svs_ref.nii.gz
old file  = ACC_svs_ref.nii.gz
new file  = sub-myid_ses-myses_voi-ACC_acq-svs_ref_mrs.nii.gz

path/file = /tmp/testd/Lt Hippocampus_svs_ECC.nii.gz
old file  = Lt Hippocampus_svs_ECC.nii.gz
new file  = sub-myid_ses-myses_voi-Lt Hippocampus_acq-svs_ECC_mrs.nii.gz

path/file = /tmp/testd/Lt Hippocampus_svs_noECC.nii.gz
old file  = Lt Hippocampus_svs_noECC.nii.gz
new file  = sub-myid_ses-myses_voi-Lt Hippocampus_acq-svs_noECC_mrs.nii.gz

path/file = /tmp/testd/Lt Hippocampus_svs_ref.nii.gz
old file  = Lt Hippocampus_svs_ref.nii.gz
new file  = sub-myid_ses-myses_voi-Lt Hippocampus_acq-svs_ref_mrs.nii.gz

path/file = /tmp/testd/Lt Hippocampus_svs_ref.json
old file  = Lt Hippocampus_svs_ref.json
new file  = sub-myid_ses-myses_voi-Lt Hippocampus_acq-svs_ref_mrs.json


oldfilename = Lt Hippocampus_svs_ref.json
newfilename = sub-myid_ses-myses_voi-Lt Hippocampus_acq-svs_ref_mrs.json


I don't quite understand the solution. The $bidsdir variable which specifies path to the folder where the 6 files (12 if you count jsons) are located isn't used in the code at all. And what is file.list?

Not sure if this is absolutely right: you'd know ;)
goose@t410:/tmp/brain$ find
.
./Lt Hippocampus_svs_ECC.nii.gz
./Lt Hippocampus_svs_ref.nii.gz
./ACC_svs_noECC.nii.gz
./Lt Hippocampus_svs_noECC.nii.gz
./ACC_svs_ECC.nii.gz
./ACC_svs_ref.nii.gz
goose@t410:/tmp/brain$ rename  -E "s/(ACC|Lt Hippocampus)/sub-${id}_ses-${ses}_voi-\1_acq/" -E "s/(ref|ECC|noECC)/\1_mrs/"   -E 's/acq_svs/acq-svs/' *.gz
\1 better written as $1 at (eval 25) line 2.
\1 better written as $1 at (eval 25) line 3.
goose@t410:/tmp/brain$ find
.
./sub-_ses-_voi-Lt Hippocampus_acq-svs_ref_mrs.nii.gz
./sub-_ses-_voi-ACC_acq-svs_ref_mrs.nii.gz
./sub-_ses-_voi-Lt Hippocampus_acq-svs_ECC_mrs.nii.gz
./sub-_ses-_voi-ACC_acq-svs_ECC_mrs.nii.gz
./sub-_ses-_voi-ACC_acq-svs_noECC_mrs.nii.gz
./sub-_ses-_voi-Lt Hippocampus_acq-svs_noECC_mrs.nii.gz

